# Android Support MediaRouter not detecting secondary displays

Tags: android, android-support-library

The Media Router support library does not find routes for Secondary Displays using the `MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_VIDEO` as stated in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/media/mediarouter.html#selector).

**Am I missing any flags or key steps that are needed for the MediaRouter to detect secondary displays?** (Code below)

Using `appcompat-v7:23.0.1` and `mediarouter-v7:23.0.1`, and could not detect simulated secondary displays or secondary diplays via MHL adapter.

Here is my MediaRouteSelector initialization:

```
mMediaRouteSelector = new MediaRouteSelector.Builder()
            .addControlCategory(MediaControlIntent.CATEGORY_LIVE_VIDEO)
            .build();
```

Here is where the selector is registered with the MediaRouter:

```
mMediaRouter.addCallback(mMediaRouteSelector, mMediaRouterCallback,
            MediaRouter.CALLBACK_FLAG_REQUEST_DISCOVERY);
```

This is the action item initialization:

```
MenuItem mediaRouteMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.media_route_menu_item);
        if (mediaRouteMenuItem != null) {
            MediaRouteActionProvider mediaRouteActionProvider =
                (MediaRouteActionProvider) MenuItemCompat.getActionProvider(mediaRouteMenuItem);
            if (mediaRouteActionProvider != null) {
                mediaRouteActionProvider.setRouteSelector(mMediaRouteSelector);
            }
        }
```

Comment: MHL displays usually are handled automatically by the device (mirroring), with optional custom control by the foreground app (via `Presentation`). You should be able to enumerate the displays using `DisplayManager`, which is what I use with my `PresentationHelper` in [my CWAC-Presentation library](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-presentation). Beyond all that, Stack Overflow is for programming questions, and it is unclear what your question is.

Comment: @CommonsWare we already use your wonderful `PresentationHelper` for detecting and presenting to displays. We are trying to add Google Cast Remote Display support, which relies on MediaRouter with  `.addControlCategory(CastMediaControlIntent.categoryForCast("APP_ID"))`. We are trying to reconcile the way displays are picked, and MediaRouter looks like it should do the job, but it doesn't. I edited my question for more clarification. I also tried your cwac-mediarouter and the sample app doesn't detect the displays either. :( Thanks for all you do!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Media router only supports wireless secondary displays such as Wireless Display for `CATEGORY_LIVE_VIDEO` - wired connections such as those with MHL are not supported in Media Router - instead it is automatically used for mirroring the display.

Comment: Thanks Ian! I think the documentation(https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/guide/topics/media/mediarouter.html#selector) can be updated to highlight that `CATEGORY_LIVE_VIDEO` **only** works with wireless displays. Should i submit a documentation "bug"?

Answer (score 0):

I created a third-party library to report Secondary Displays, we which so affectionately named [SecondaryDisplayMediaRouteProvider](https://github.com/SteadfastInnovation/SecondaryDisplayMediaRouteProvider).